# How can I stop being electrocuted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

In Feed The Beast, I have this setup with an MFE, a low voltage transformer, some gold cables, and my other machines. Whenever I touch the MFE, transformer, or gold cables, I get shocked. This somewhat annoys me because I have died twice. Here is a picture for reference:[image] In case you can't see, that is a gold cable behind the words "Death Point".

My question: How can I stop being shocked by the gold cables?

---

As per @Shinrai 's instructions, I have made my circuits less exposed and how I use glass fibre cables.

If you can't see, this is a MFE in the blank space connected to some solar panels.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because they carry significantly higher voltage than copper cables, you actually need to put multiple layers of insulation on gold cables.  (You can do this by crafting the insulated cables with more rubber like you to do get them in the first place).

Having said that, I believe you may still take a small amount of damage even from 2x insulated gold cables.  Consider concealing your wiring entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You need to insulate your gold cables multiple times. Same with HV iron cables if you eventually start using those. Your best bet is to insulate your cables as much as you can and then perhaps seal them off in a "maintenance area".